# How to get days left in Carbon

Tags: php, php-carbon

I want to send an email to a user twice: 3 days and 1 day before a certain expiry date. So for an expiry date of **13/04/2019** I want send email on **10/04/2019** and **12/04/2019**.

I have this code but it doesn't work right:

```
if($expireDate <= Carbon::now()->subDays(3) && $expireDate <= Carbon::now()->subDays(1)){
  Mail::to($userEmail)->send(new UserPlanNearExpire($planName, $expireDate, $user));
}
```

## Update

This is my job handle method

```
public function handle()
{
    $userCurrentType = User::get();
    foreach($userCurrentType as $user)
    {
        $userEmail = $user->email;
        $user = $user;

        foreach($user->invoices as $invoice){
            $planName = $invoice->type->name;
            $expireDate = $invoice->plan_expire;
        }
        //sending email
        $expireDate = new Carbon($expireDate);
        $days = $expireDate->diffInDays();
        if ($days === 1 or $days === 3) {
            Mail::to($userEmail)->send(new UserPlanNearExpire($planName, $expireDate, $user));
        }
    }
}
```

**The logic:**

Here is my database, normally I should get two emails for users with id `1` and `2` as they are `1` and `3` days away from expire date.

[image: one]

**What I get:**

I get only one email for first user, first I thought maybe it's because my mailing code is inside `foreach (loop)` but when I moved it out of loop it didn't send any mail :)

[image: two]

**Any idea?**

Comment: shouldn't it be `||` instead of `&&` ?

Comment: @DerekPollard even without second part it doesn't send email in right time, do you have any idea?

Comment: Also, you're using `<=` so that's going to catch multiple days between 1 and 3.

Comment: @miken32 what should i use? please share your thoughts.